# XPath for Multiple Elements (None Required) with Separator Between

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working with an xml document intended to index elements of digital library record and trying to navigate using two very different xml schemas that we want indexed in the same way (Dublin Core and MODS, to be specific.)

For DC, we have subjects expressed very simply as such:

```
<dc:subject>Text string--text string--text string.</subject>
```

However, in MODS, this is more complex and specific, the same information expressed as:

```
<subject authority="lcsh">
    <name type="corporate">
        <namePart>Text string</namePart>
    </name>
    <titleInfo>
        <title></title>
    </titleInfo>
    <topic>Text string</topic>
    <genre>Text string</genre>
</subject>                        <!-- Added by edit -->
```

Not all of the sub-elements of subject will be present at one time. While I have them displaying so that they look identical in the interface for our users, I am somewhat stumped on how to deal with this in our custom indexer.

The index specifically pulls from a given xpath. In DC, this works fine, because everything is already in one element:

```
<term indexName="subject" displayName="Subject" xpath="//dc:subject"/>
```

However, in MODS this is more complicated. I understand that I can use | between the different elements to return data from them all, but this would still not match the data in dc:subject due to the lack of the -- separators.

I have no control over the schema document for the indexer (proprietary), and I can't use xslt, so my options are limited. I am wondering, is there a way I could  rewrite this to return a string made of the four sub-elements and a separator?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have XPath-1.0 available and can live with empty sections, the following XPath expression may fit:

```
concat(name/namePart/text(),' -- ',titleInfo/title/text(),' -- ',topic/text(),' -- ',genre/text())
```

Its result is

```
Text string --  -- Text string -- Text string
```

---

With XPath-2.0 you can use conditional expressions to avoid empty sections:

```
concat(
    if (normalize-space(name/namePart/text())) then 
        concat(name/namePart/text(),' -- ') 
    else '', 
    if (normalize-space(titleInfo/title/text())) then 
        concat(titleInfo/title/text(),' -- ' )
    else '', 
    if (normalize-space(topic/text())) then 
        concat(topic/text(),' -- ') 
    else '', 
    if (normalize-space(genre/text())) then 
        genre/text() 
    else ''
)
```

Its output is

```
Text string -- Text string -- Text string
```

This is not a perfect solution, but sufficiently adaptable to your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

This xpath expression works for me:

```
xpath="concat(subject/name/namePart, substring(' -- ',1,number(subject/name/namePart!='')*4) , subject/titleInfo/title, substring(' -- ',1,number(subject/titleInfo/title!='')*4), subject/topic, substring(' -- ',1,number(subject/topic!='')*4), subject/genre)"
```